# Can a custom vscode editor be notified when the theme changes in vscode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I have a custom editor that uses shadow dom this code will be used in multiple scenarios inside vscode and outside so although vscode's theme css custom properties penetrate shadow dom I dont want code in my editor that directly references vscode css properties eg.

.my-css-class
{
color:var(--vscode-fore-color)
}

My alternative approach is to grab the values of certain vscode css custom props and pass them into my web components via setAttribute and then assign them to internal css custom properties. This works but cannot respond when theme is changed.

Is there a way to hook into a themeChangedEvent in vscode, i see internally there is something for this but not sure if or how I could hook into this from my editor.

Comment: Do you mean from an extension?  There is a `onDidChangeActiveColorTheme` event listener you could use.

Comment: Yes that is what I tried already but did not seem to work its does not fire when changing the theme, thanks for confirming I am in the right area though maybe I have implemented it incorrectly but not seeing any examples

Comment: Ok got it working I was putting the code in the wrong location, thanks for the assist Mark

Comment: Added this inside register function context.subscriptions.push(
      vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveColorTheme((editor) => {
        if (editor) {
          if (OTDocument.logging === true) {
            OTDocument.channel.appendLine('Theme test: ');
          }
        }
      })
    );

Comment: You should add your working code as an answer.